# Compiler error (ld: library not found for -lzbar)

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

When I build my project, I met below error. Anybody know that and please help me solve.
Note: this error only on XCode 4.2 - Lion, everything ok if I build on XCode 4.2 - Snow Leopard

ld: library not found for -lzbar
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: you are using static library lzbar which is not available in your project. Try to add this .a file to your project once again on your new Lion machine.

Answer (score 2):

Your project is using the ZBar bar code reader SDK. You're probably missing the file libzbar.a. Download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/iPhoneSDK/ZBarSDK-1.2.dmg/download).

Answer (score 0):

If you have this file in your tree a temporary fix I have seen that works with ZBar is to remove the libzbar.a library from the 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' section then clean the project then drag that library back in from your project file directory so it reappears in the section then Run.